# Code Simplification Help : Is there a way to not use a million if/else-if statements in the given situation?

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization, simplify

I am currently coding a small translator that converts English into 1337, and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do so. I currently have the code written below to return corresponding strings as they are inputed to the function. I would like to optimize this (coding and memory). Thanks in advance for any help! :-)

```
if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“a”){ return “@";}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“b”){ return “|3”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“c”){ return “<”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“d”){ return “|)”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“e”){ return “3”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“f”){ return “|*”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“g”){ return “6”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“h”){ return “/-/”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“i”){ return “!”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“j”){ return “_|”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“k”){ return “|<”;}
else if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(“l”){ return “1”;}
...
..
.
```

Comment: Put your from/to strings into a `HashMap<String, String>`.

Comment: Why does your question have smart quotes in code?

Comment: because it is copied from pdf

Comment: Yep! The program is on my phone, yet I wrote this question on my computer. Jigar is correct. Thanks for all the help, btw :D

Answer (score 3):

use `Map<String, String>` and just lookup,

To take the controll of mapping external to application, you can create a properties file and read it on load or on some trigger to load/refresh the lookup data structure

Comment: And maybe a config file...+1 though

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example, you can take advantage of the fact that chars can be array indexes:

```
String[] leet = new String[] { "@", "|3", "<", ... };
```

Lookup is:

```
public String toLeet(char ch) {
    return ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' ? leet[ch - 'A'] :
        ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' ? leet[ch - 'a'] : String.valueOf(ch)));
}
```